Why does the line not cross b value/ y-intercept as per expectation?
X=([-0.71239066,  0.45181234, -0.04450308,  0.75376638])
y=([ 44.18419163, 135.39949674,  96.51318381, 159.05759577])
y_pred1 = ((78.35 * X) + b).reshape(4)

plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.plot(X,reg.predict(X),color='red',label='OLS')
plt.plot(X,y_pred1,color='#00a65a',label='b = {}'.format(b))
plt.plot(X,y_pred,color='#A3E4D7',label='b = 0')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

I am using Matplotlib to draw regression lines. here is equation
78.35 * X  + 100.... here y line should be intercept at 100
78.35 * X  + 40.... here y line should be intercepted at 40
78.35 * X  + 0.... here y the line should be intercepted at 0
But it doesn't happend.It is hard for me to understand that why it happened.Please check picture for matlib result 

It would be helpful to see the code that you used to produce the plots

please check code .Code use matlibplot library

Can you provide some working code? It's hard to determine the issue when the code is incomplete / can't be run.

The code does not work as it is. I convertes Xand yinto numpy arrays and removed two of the 3 plot-commands to get it running. It showed me the correct line and not the line from your plot. Furthermore: these are not the y-values from your scatter plot.

I honestly would like to help you, but if you ask what is wrong with a plot and then post code that does not produce this plot, how do you think we can answer the question.
